# WPF WrapPanel inside WrapPanel without free space

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, wrappanel

I have the following situation:
Inside my main page, I have an ItemsControl and the ItemsPanelTemplate is set to a WrapPanel

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding StepItems}" x:Name="ItemsControl" Visibility="{Binding ActualView, Converter={StaticResource ActualViewConverter}, ConverterParameter=TableView}" Width="{Binding TableWidth}" Margin="0,5,0,0">
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0,5,10,5"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel x:Name="itemsWrapPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></WrapPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

The bound List "StepITems" contains several controls which itself also represents an ItemsControl as WrapPanel

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rows, ElementName=Root}" x:Name="ItemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel x:Name="itemsWrapPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"></WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <hmiControl:ScrewPointControl Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The Problem is now, that if the next list has not enough space inside the actual row, it starts in a new row, instead of wrapping.

[Three ItemsControls with space between each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpby8.png)

Is there a way to manage that the second ItemsControl starts directly after the first and then the second wraps if there is no space anymore?

Greetings,
Caipigott